# How to set height of jspdf dynamically

Tags: angular, jspdf

While creating jspdf object: new jspdf("p","mm",[80,120]), we are specifying height:120 of our document, but I want it dynamic to adjust its height according to content. The other thing is I want all data on single page, without creating another page.

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6sAg.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it doing the process two times, one for get the real height and the other for rendering.

Phase 1 (calculate height) lets say method name is getPdfHeight()

when creating the jspdf pass format property like this:

`format: [210, 90000]` (make him believe he has a lot of height space)

then in the hook assign to a outside variable:

```
didDrawPage: (data) => {
          totalHeight = data.cursor.y;
        }
```

return **totalHeight**;

Phase 2 (render):

```
toPdf() {
    const height = this.getPdfHeight();
    const doc = new jsPdf({
      orientation: "portrait",
      compress: true,
      format: [210, height + 50], //Extra space at the end
    });
```